# Is it possible to extract only embedded documents from a Model in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'd like to run a query on a Model, but only return embedded documents where the query matches. Consider the following...

```
var EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    typ : { type: String },
    meta : { type: String }
});

var DaySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    uid: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    events: [EventSchema],

    dateR: { type: Date, 'default': Date.now }

});

function getem() {
    DayModel.find({events.typ : 'magic'}, function(err, days) {
         // magic. ideally this would return a list of events rather then days    
    });

}
```

That find operation will return a list of DayModel documents. But what I'd really like is a list of EventSchemas alone. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to fetch the Event objects directly, but you can restrict which fields your query returns like this:

```
DayModel.find({events.typ : 'magic'}, ['events'], function(err, days) {
   ...
});
```

You will still need to loop through the results to extract the actual embedded fields from the documents returned by the query, however.